# spring-security with spring-boot,custom login page,error 403

Tags: html, spring-security, spring-boot

I use spring-boot and spring-security to build the project, using a custom login page 404 times wrong, I want to do is to separate the login page and project, and to authenticate the user information sent using Ajax URL on the login page, but always wrong 403, I changed the configuration information for the spring boot security configue but there is no specific effect. The following code:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
}
```

send post url:localhost:8888/login
params: username,password
response: 403

ERROR MESSAGE :

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Expected csrf token not found. Has your session expired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure post to include csrf token from Spring Security. You have to set header parameter "X-CSRF-TOKEN" in your POST request. Example POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", "${_csrf.token}");
    },

    ///...

});
```